# How do I debug ngrx/store?

Tags: angular, ngrx

I have run into a specific code state with Angular 2 and ngrx/store where my application breaks totally (routing not working, data not appearing, route singing back to previous one, and all other kinds of possible disasters), but I am running out of idea how to debug what's happening around the store. The redux dev-tools is a great tool, but it does not seem to be able to catch errors.

I have placed `.catch` statements throughout my selectors, effects, and just before `.subscribe()` statements, trying out two variants:

```
return state$.select(state => state.user)
  .map(user => user.collection)
  .catch((error, caught) => {
      console.log('error getCollection');
      return caught;
  });
```

and

```
return state$.select(state => state.user)
  .map(user => user.collection)
  .catch((error) => {
      console.log('error getCollection');
      return Observable.throw(error);
  });
```

The console remains silent though. I simply don't believe there would be any other "single source of error" but the store.

This code does not catch error for me. Should it?:

```
.do(() => {
    Observable.throw('fake error');
})
.catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
    return Observable.throw(error);
});
```

Can anyone point me at how to debug the observables used throughout the store?

Answer (score 2):

use .do() for logging a stream - that will fix it

you will need to add the do operator via an RXJS import.

```
return state$
  .do(() => { // log here } )
  .select(state => state.user)
  .map(user => user.collection)
  .catch((error, caught) => {
      console.log('error getCollection');
      return caught;
  });
```

Comment: But how is it supposed to give me information on wrong things going on, as it will log unconditionally?

Comment: it is logging what it emitted from the stream

Comment: you could also do ... .map.do to see what map is doing ... etc

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but it basically duplicates all I can see in the Redux tab of ngrx/store-devtools in Chrome. I would really like to know what's bad about the catch.

This code does not catch error. Should it?
```
.do(() => {
    Observable.throw('fake error');
})
.catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
    return Observable.throw(error);
});
```

Comment: Your subscribe has 3 functions. The first is NEXT. The second is ERROR. The third is COMPLETE. returning Observable.throw ends the stream and calls the ERROR block. If that's not what you want return Observable.from(['somethingToEmitToNextFunction']) to prevent the stream from falling over and to call the NEXT function. Or return Observable.empty() from the catch block to do nothing (will stop stream falling over). You can experiment with other returns ... see https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Creating-Observables